# Dynamically fill an SQL table by detecting a name?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to dynamically fill a SQL table by detecting duplicate names. So, when I use an insert statement on this table - if the name already exists it adds an entry with the same ID.

What I mean by this, for example I've got this empty table:

**Table Domain:**

| DomainID | Name | URL | StatusID | ErrorID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |

So when I use these insert statements (please ignore StatusID, ErrorID and Date):

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Domain (Name, URL, StatusID, ErrorID, Date) VALUES('google', 'google.com', 0, 0, null)   
        
INSERT INTO dbo.Domain (Name, URL, StatusID, ErrorID, Date) VALUES('yahoo', 'yahoo.com', 0, 0, null) 
          
INSERT INTO dbo.Domain (Name, URL, StatusID, ErrorID, Date) VALUES('google', 'google.com', 0, 0, null)
```

The table should look like this:

| DomainID | Name | URL | StatusID | ErrorID | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | google | https://google.com | 0 | 0 | null |
| 2 | yahoo | https://yahoo.com | 0 | 0 | null |
| 1 | google | https://google.com | 0 | 0 | null |

Is there a way that it can detect an existing entry for 'google', checks the ID and inserts the same ID as the already existing entry?

Comment: Are you able to modify your insert statement?

Comment: ``DomainID`` should not be as ``Identity``. and use row number to evaluate it.

Comment: Yes. I am in full control of everything.

Comment: How are you currently generating DomainID and is it related to your primary key? Because if so you can't have duplicate values.

Comment: Currently DomainID is an Identity. It's the primary key. But I can basically change everything. Not all entries in Domain have to be unique, because I will be using this DB for web monitoring. But it would be handy if every Domain Name had a unique ID linked to it.

Comment: Why bother setting the ID the same when you already have the name the same? If you want to set the ID the same you'll need another ID column, because you need a PK, and the PK must be unique. This is sounding like and X/Y problem, you'd be better off telling us why you want the data this way, there is probably a better solution all around.

Comment: Okay, so let's add ID, which I'll make the Identity & PK. Still, how does linking DomainID (which is no longer Identity and PK) to Name work? Or should I just - like you said - use the Name value and no ID? I'm an intern in a company. I need to monitor the intranet domains daily for status using a powershell script. The validation works already, I just need to add my results to a database. + These results should accessible and readable by the web admin who will convert these results to a data, graphs, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ID of a row has to be unique for each rows otherwise it's not an identifier. In your table schema `DomainID` is reduntant: it does not add any relevant information. You can remove this field and use `URL` but your table schema will lack a primary key.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a Composite Primary Key of Name and Date, since these are the relevant fields of data for web monitoring, since using an ID is redundant in this case, as Ad Fortia mentioned.

[image: Current schema]